# Sizeof a struct?

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I am doing a UNIX socket practice and trying to create a socket that's similar to a stream socket [example](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/us_xfr_sv.c.html), but I realize that in the example code, the 3rd parameter passed to `memset()` is the `sizeof` a `struct`:

```
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
```

where `addr` is declared in the beginning of the program as a definition of `struct sockaddr_un`. How can the program know the `sizeof` a struct that has not been initialized? Because when I did the same thing in my program, GCC gives me an error. Thanks.

Comment: Can you guess the size of a 32-bit integer without having instantialized one? So can the compiler.

Comment: Wait, am I the only person who thinks instantialized is not actually a word?

Comment: What error do you get? “GCC gives me an error” is not a useful error description.

Comment: Instantiate isn't a word typically used in the context of C.  That's a C++/Objective-C notion.  The struct is defined which is the only important thing.  Once it has been defined, it doesn't matter whether or not it has been used, you still know how big it is.

Comment: @JeremyWest you're right, the correct word is instantiate, but it shouldn't be used here anyway. Thanks.

Comment: all the program needs is the 'definition' of the struct, not an 'instance' of the struct nor does any instance of the struct need to be initialized to any specific values.    Also, note that the 'sizeof' operator is a compile time item, not a run time item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the program know the sizeof a struct that has not been instantialized?

Same as `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(char)`, etc. You don't need variable to be initialized before applying `sizeof`, all you need is the type of the variable.

> Because when I did the same thing in my program, GCC gives me an error.

In your case, check if you have included proper headers for Unix socket:

```
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <sys/un.h>
```

Comment: And the type has to be complete, which might have been what bit OP but we might never know as OP doesn't gave enough details.

Comment: Yes, he might have forgotten the proper headers I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.